# What would be the easiest way to determine GPU presence in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu

Im my app I render images differently depending on GPU presence (using OpenGL when there's a GPU).

Currently I have a configuration option for that.

But I want my app to detect GPU presence automatically by some method, some quick test. I think there's no direct API which allows that. However, what should be the test then?

Comment: we can check the no of procesors using    final int i = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

Comment: @Chintan Not sure if it counts GPU, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite as easy as a boolean, but you can try things like

```
glGetString(GL_VENDOR);
glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
```

And try to determine it based on a known list of GPU vendors. This is what OpenGL man page has to say about it:

> Because the GL does not include queries for the performance
>               characteristics of an implementation, some applications are written to
>               recognize known platforms and modify their GL usage based on known
>               performance characteristics of these platforms.
>               Strings GL_VENDOR and GL_RENDERER together uniquely specify
>               a platform. They do not change from release to release and should be used
>               by platform-recognition algorithms.

Just for an example, my device returns:

```
Vendor:   NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer: NVIDIA Tegra
```